# Application error on Heroku. An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have deployed my first app on Heroku. The app was working. I did some css styling, added a gem and added a widget. After pushing to Heroku I started getting this error.
Application error,
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
I deleted all changes and deleted the gem and I'm still getting the same error.
Can someone please help.
This is what my logs says.

Application Logs

---

```
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070388+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-2.0.1/lib/rack/server.rb:282:in `start'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070390+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:79:in `start'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070392+00:00 app[web.1]:    from   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:90:in `block in server'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070394+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070398+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070396+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070400+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-5.0.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070402+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'  
2016-12-19T07:39:21.070421+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'  
2016-12-19T12:18:12.445785+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App    crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=b19b4989-195e-4dd9-b9d4-be040f005567 fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=  
2016-12-19T12:18:12.883504+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=da691f65-a247-4486-be41-5e40a24bf73d fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:06.946508+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=2742ae66-fc1a-41f3-a7a1-34f19d80be2c fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:07.336515+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=b0fb1a59-64b3-4b94-a5d4-cf620e3522b1 fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:35.432525+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=2ec59492-b01c-48bc-85b1-d8cb836429ce fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:35.816449+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=d80af4e9-e11d-4117-a2f0-c03e5a5df940 fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:44.824487+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=ec97a999-1805-4755-b975-fc497ca7f4dc fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=   
2016-12-19T12:19:45.234548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=bark-sj.herokuapp.com request_id=a5501bea-0322-4053-8b80-9fd4a62e49ac fwd="71.75.222.70" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the error details in this chunk,  can you post more of the error log? it might help to use heroku logs --tails, sometimes that can show you a little more in your terminal when you visit the page and get the error

Comment: I just updated the most resent log. Thats for replying,

Comment: did you add anything new to the database locally before you pushed up whatever it was that you pushed up to heroku?

Comment: no but i did do a heroku rake db:migrate before I made this post.